# Adding Google API Java Client Library and Calendar API Java Library to Maven dependencies

Tags: android, maven, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have an Android project using Google Calendar v3 API.

I'm using [Google API Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)  and [Calendar API Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API) Libraries to perform queries on Google Calendar.

I have problems setting up maven dependencies. I've added those libraries to my pom.xml using ids from documentation, but some of them were outdated, so I've ended up with this [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/a0DxCs22)

I had to put `<scope>provided</scope>` to google-api-client, google-http-client-jackson and google-http-client-android libraries because maven was failing when trying to dex those libs.

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.4.1:dex (default-dex)
```

Now this pom.xml successfully creates .apk and installs it on device. But when I trying to make queries to Calendar API using provided libraries, an app fails, saying that it cannot find some classes.

```
12-19 17:32:17.247: E/dalvikvm(15119): Could not find class 'com.google.api.services.calendar.model.TimePeriod', referenced from method
```

When I'm building an app from Eclipse (all .jars are in the /libs folder) everything is ok.

So I wonder if there is a correct way to add those dependencies to Maven script. 
Google has a lot of an outdated documentation with non-working links or samples.
Otherwise I'd have to get rid of Google libraries and write Calendar API queries by myself.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**ANSWER:**

xpp3.jar was causing the problem because it has classes from javax package. I had to manually exclude it from all Google libraries:

```
            <exclusion>
                  <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                  <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
```

Comment: So if you're trying to add these api to your application the build process fails (please provide more concrete error). And if you don't add these libraries to app the runtime fails. Looks like you need to figure out what should be included and what will be really provided by Android runtime

Comment: Exactly. I've added some of them with <scope>provided</scope> and now maven builds .apk but at runtime Dalvik can't find some classes. I've updated the question with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artem,

I see next error and advice how to fix it:

```
[INFO] trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
[INFO]
[INFO] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
[INFO] when not building a core library.
```

This is Java core file. Try to figure out what dependencies are using it with (`mvn dependency:tree`).

Comment: Thanks for help, the error appeared because I forgot to exclude xpp3 from Google Calendar API library.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use scope provided since these libraries are NOT part of the Android stack and therefore need to be included into your apk. What are the failures you are getting when including them with default scope?

Update:

As suspected you are trying to include a javax namespace project. Try to find out what the dependency is that is causing it with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and then potentially either exclude it (assuming that same class is in android already) or shade it into a different namespace (and update the library to use it) or find a better suited library..

Comment: When I'm removing scope provided from Google Api Client maven build fails when trying to do dex goal. Here is a raw output of dex step with -e and -X flags: http://pastebin.com/8WxDFQbL

Comment: Thanks for help, the error appeared because I forgot to exclude xpp3 from Google Calendar API library.